# Zalenium fails to start err : nginx: [error] failed to initialize Lua VM in /home/seluser/nginx.conf:107 - Mac M1

Tags: docker, selenium, nginx, zalenium

I am Trying to start Zalenium in Mac M1

it fails with below error
Docker binary already present, will use that one.

Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4

-- LOG 10:31:39:034127379 Ensuring docker works...

-- LOG 10:31:39:669157254 Ensuring docker-selenium is available...

haveged: haveged starting up

Copying files for Dashboard...

Starting Nginx reverse proxy...

nginx: [error] failed to initialize Lua VM in /home/seluser/nginx.conf:107

Starting Selenium Hub...

.haveged: haveged: RNDADDENTROPY failed!

.qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped

............................................................................................................................................................................................/zalenium.sh: line 307:   193 Segmentation fault      java ${ZALENIUM_EXTRA_JVM_PARAMS} -Dlogback.loglevel=${DEBUG_MODE} -Dlogback.appender=${LOGBACK_APPENDER} -Dlogback.configurationFile=${LOGBACK_PATH} -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging_${DEBUG_MODE}.properties -cp ${ZALENIUM_ARTIFACT} org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3 -role hub -port 4445 -newSessionWaitTimeout ${NEW_SESSION_WAIT_TIMEOUT} -browserTimeout ${SEL_BROWSER_TIMEOUT_SECS} -registry de.zalando.ep.zalenium.registry.ZaleniumRegistry ${SELENIUM_HUB_PARAMS} ${DEBUG_FLAG}

GridLauncher failed to start after 1 minute, failing...

curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4444: Connection refused

---- X ------

Command Used to Start zalenium:

docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos --privileged dosel/zalenium start --desiredContainers 4

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That will likely not work as the Docker Selenium containers are based on x86 binaries.